# Serializing a data object AND a form field for $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do something like this

```
$.getJSON('/server/validate_field', { what:'validate', email_address:field.serialize() },     function(data)
```

then the query string ends up like this

```
validate_field?what=validate&email_address=email_address%3Dasdk%2540lal.com
```

Notice the duplicate. How can I fix this without having to manually create a key value pair for the form data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`field.serialize()` returns a pre-formatted querystring, which is not what you want.

You just want the field's value: `field.val()`.
jQuery will serialize that along with the rest of your object when sending the request.

Comment: I was hoping for a technique which I didn't have to explicitly name the keys for the form data. Serialize already creates a nice query string by itself...I just want to add the data from the object to it.